# Solve $e^{k_1/x}+e^{k_2/x}+\cdots+e^{k_N/x}=1$ for $x$

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-sum

How can I solve $e^{k_1/x}+e^{k_2/x}+\cdots+e^{k_N/x}=1$ for $x$,

where $N\geq 1, k_1,\ldots,k_N \in \mathbb{R}, k_1,\ldots,k_N < 0, x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x >0$.

I looked at the basic rules of exponentiation and logarithms and they do not seem to help simplify the equation in this particular case.

As a side comment: the values of $N$ I am working with are $N\approx 10^6$.

Comment: The right-hand-side is increasing in $x$.  What about a simple bisection search? Take two values $x_{left}$ and $x_{right}$ such that $x_{left} \leq x^* \leq x_{right}$.  Then test $(x_{right}+x_{left})/2$ and form a new "left" or "right" endpoint based on the result.  The search interval decreases by a factor of 2 every step.  Exponential convergence rate.

Comment: @Michael that might be the best option, thanks

Comment: Is there some more context for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$f(x)
= e^{k_1/x}+e^{k_2/x}+\cdots+e^{k_N/x}-1
=\sum_{i=1}^N e^{k_i/x}-1
$,
and let
$K = \sum_{i=1}^N k_i
$.

The restrictions that
$x > 0$
and
$k_i < 0$
are important in what follows.

$f'(x)
=\sum -\frac{k_i}{x^2}e^{k_i/x}
=-\frac1{x^2}\sum k_ie^{k_i/x}
=\frac1{x^2}\sum |k_i|e^{k_i/x}
$,
so
$f'(x) > 0$.
This means that
your function has
at most one root.
Since $f(x) < 0$
for small $x$
and
$f(x) > 0$
for large $x$,
$f$ has exactly one positive root.

To get simple bounds
on the root of
$f(x) = 0$,
let
$k_{min} = \min(k_i)$
and
$k_{max} = \max(k_i)$.
Note that,
since the $k_i < 0$,
$|k_{min}|
>|k_{max}|
$.

Then
$e^{k_{min}/x}
\le e^{k_i/x}
\le e^{k_{max}/x}
$
so
$e^{k_{min}/x}
\le \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N e^{k_i/x}}{N}
\le e^{k_{max}/x}
$.
If
$f(x) = 0
$, then
$e^{k_{min}/x}
\le \dfrac{1}{N}
\le e^{k_{max}/x}
$
or
$k_{min}/x
\le -\ln(N)
\le k_{max}/x
$
or,
since $k_i < 0$,
$|k_{min}|/x
\ge \ln(N)
\ge |k_{max}|/x
$
or
$\frac{|k_{max}|}{\ln(N)}
\le x
\le \frac{|k_{min}|}{\ln(N)}
$.

Another bound can be gotten using
$e^z \ge 1+z$.
$f(x)
\ge \sum (1+k_i/x) - 1
= N+\frac1{x}\sum k_i - 1
= N+\frac{K}{x} - 1
$.
If
$f(x) = 0$,
then
$1-N 
\ge \frac{K}{x}
= -\frac{|K|}{x}
$
or
$N-1 
\le \frac{|K|}{x}
$
or
$x \le \frac{|K|}{N-1}
$.

This can be improved
by using the inequality
between the arithmetic and geometric means.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N e^{k_i/x}}{N}
&\ge \left(\prod_{i=1}^N e^{k_i/x}\right)^{1/N}\\
&= e^{\sum_{i=1}^N k_i/(Nx)}\\
&= e^{K/(Nx)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $f(x) = 0$,
$\dfrac1{N}
\ge e^{K/(Nx)}
$
or
$-\ln(N)
\ge K/(Nx)
$
or
$\ln(N) \le |K|/(Nx)
$
or
$x \le \dfrac{|K|}{N\ln(N)}
$.

So an initial $x$
could be
$x_0
=\frac{|K|}{N\ln(N)}
$.

We can then apply
Newton's iteration,
$x_{n+1}
=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$
a few times
and see what happens.
It should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to finding roots of the polynomial

$$y^{-k_1}+\cdots +y^{-k_N}-1=0$$

(by making $y:= e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$) so your problem is as difficult as finding roots of polynomials. It depends on the degree of that polynomial, in this case, it depends on the max of the $-k_i$.

Comment: I thought in a polynomial all the exponents had to be integers.

Comment: And that's the case, I'm sorry, I didn't notice that in the statement. If the $k_i$ are rationals, there's still some hope by multiplying $-\frac{1}{x}$ by some power of $10$ such that, when multiplied by each $k_i$, the result is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Write an algorithm to solve the problem...

Let

> $$
> Q = \left( \sum_{m=1}^{n} \exp(k_m y) - 1 \right)^2.
> $$

In case we have the solution, we have
$$
Q = 0
$$.

For changes in $Q$ we have

> $$
> \delta Q = 2 Q \left( \sum_{m=1}^{n} k_m \exp(k_m y) \right) \delta y.
> $$

For each step use

> $$
> \delta y = - 2 Q \left( \sum_{m=1}^{n} k_m \exp(k_m y) \right),
> $$

whence

> $$
> \delta Q \le 0,
> $$

so we get closer to the solution.

Once you have found $y$, the solution for $x$ is given by

> $$
> x = \frac{1}{y}.
> $$

This would do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What is Q? Why is the right hand side squared in the first equation? I also don't know what changes and steps you are talking about.

Comment: @nmamg $Q$ is just a definition, call it "Quality". When you have found the solution for $y$, then $Q=0$ - if $y$ differs from the solution, then $Q>0$, the higher the value of $Q$ the worse is the solution.